# How to automatically resize expanded rows?

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, row

So my problem is that I have a sheet in which a multitude of grouped rows exist. The rows are grouped in 2 levels. To put this in perspective, I have a group which covers the rows in A1:A55. Inside this first level group I have multiple second level groups covering smaller sections (e.g. rows in A2:A5, rows in A7:A10 and so on.). Because of Excel automatically adding groups together if they are adjacent to each other, I have added a blank row in between each 2nd level group of rows(A6, A11, etc.). I then proceeded to change the height of these blank rows to 0,00. This hid the + and - signs on the left hand bar for collapsing/expanding, which wasn't a problem as the collapsing and expanding is being handled via buttons on the sheet.

However, when all the grouped rows, or just the 2nd level grouped rows, are being expanded (either manually or via a macro), the row height of all the blank rows jumps back to a size at which Excel can display the + and - signs in the left hand bar again. This shows the blank rows which I want to prevent.

I know I probably can't prevent the resizing of the rows so it displays the + and - signs, however I was thinking about immediately resizing the blank rows to a height of 0.00. This is being built in the macro that is called via the buttons, but the concern is when a user expands the rows manually. There is no event for collapsing and or expanding for me to use in an event handler. Is there any way for me to have an automatic response on a manual expand action by the user?

I have provided a example of the code used below.

```
Sub Select1Year_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Overview")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Selection Tab")
Dim ROffset As Integer
ROffset = ((ws2.Range("B33").Value - 1) * 4)    'User defined starting Year 
                                                'value

On Error Resume Next
With ws1
    .Range("AJ2").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2018
    .Range("AJ7").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2019
    .Range("AJ12").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2020
    .Range("AJ17").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2021
    .Range("AJ22").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2022
    .Range("AJ27").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2023
    .Range("AJ32").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2024
    .Range("AJ37").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2025
    .Range("AJ42").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2026
    .Range("AJ47").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2027
    .Range("AJ52").Rows.ShowDetail = False    '2028
End With

If ws2.Range("B31").Value = 1 Then    'User selected 1 year to be shown in 
                                      'expanded view
    ws1.Range("AJ2").Offset(0, ROffset).Rows.ShowDetail = True
End If

End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub Select10Year_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Overview")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Selection Tab")
Dim i As Integer
Dim ROffset As Integer
ROffset = ((ws2.Range("B33").Value - 1) * 4)    'User defined starting Year 
                                                'value

If ws2.Range("B31").Value = 3 Then    'User selected all years to be expanded
    On Error Resume Next
    ws1.Shapes("Select10Year").ControlFormat.Value = True
    With ws1
        .Range("AJ2").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2018
        .Range("AJ7").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2019
        .Range("AJ12").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2020
        .Range("AJ27").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2021
        .Range("AJ22").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2022
        .Range("AJ27").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2023
        .Range("AJ32").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2024
        .Range("AJ37").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2025
        .Range("AJ42").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2026
        .Range("AJ47").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2027
        .Range("AJ52").Rows.ShowDetail = True    '2028
    End With
    If ROffset > 0 Then    'User has selected a different starting year then 
                           '2018, so collapse are years before selected 
                           'starting year
        For i = 0 To i = ROffset Step 1
            ws1.Range("AJ2").Offset(0, ROffset).Rows.ShowDetail = False
        Next i
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the show/hide is never done manually with +/- buttons then would it be an alternative way for you to just show/hide rows without grouping just by using VBA eg `Rows(5).Hidden = True`? This way you can show/hide any row individually and you don't need a spacer row at all.

Comment: Let me reiterate, it should never be done on the 2nd level. However, it is possible for users to do so, as the first level expansion is used as a quick filter of sorts (per user request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your macro being launched as a result of a `Worksheet_Change()` event.

Comment: Collapsing/expanding rows falls under a worksheet_change() event? Sounds great, imma try it out, thanks in advance!